# VisualVM, Scala and Ubuntu?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, visualvm

I have a problem with VisualVM under Ubuntu 11.10 (64bit). I'm using the latest Java 1.6 version (1.6.0_29-b11) and Scala 2.9.1.

VisualVM does not show me CPU Usage in the Monitor's Tab (says: Not supported for this JVM.), the Threads Tab is missing and I cannot use the Sampler or Profiler. Actually I can click on CPU Profiling but nothing happens.

Everything works perfectly fine under Windows 7!

In the VisualVM logs I find this exception a few times:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I've never experienced problems with VisualVM and Scala under Linux. But I'm not sure about your exact configuration.

Comment: Obviously the visualVM cannot connect to that JVM. Try using the older jconsole that you should still find in the java/bin folder to see whether that can connect.

Comment: I have seen this on applications that are very cpu intensive, but after running a few times it worked. Are you using open JDK or the Oracle java?

Comment: @dimitrisli that didn't work out. JConsole said it cannot connect to my application.

Comment: For me both Jconsole and visualvm cannot connect to JVM if I try to debug my code. But they can easily connect with JVM if I am not running my code in debug mode. Please note I have centos and I run my program and mem profiler with sudo

Comment: Can anyone please highlight whats the reason for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often sen things like this that are related to permissions. Make sure you have the correct permissions and/or are running as the same user as the JVM.

Comment: I'm running the application and VisualVM with the same user. I tried now to run both as `super user` and that **worked** - kinda weird that only my application requires this. I can connect to any other application (IntelliJ for example) without any problem. But mine seems to require super user permissions when using VisualVM even though in general it runs perfectly fine with _normal_ rights. So why is that the case?

Comment: Which are the debug ports? Normal users are not allowed to open ports below 1024 or something.

Comment: I am running IntelliJ and visualvm with superuser, it works in case if I am not debugging. But If I debug my code in IntelliJ I get the above error. This is strange for me to understand, why this is happening although Sudo run applications have the same access level.